# Modifiying an APK file to make minor changes

Tags: android, apk

First, I'm not a developer, just a guy who knows some basic programming and who wants to make a -seemingly- easy task. I have an APK file which was originally created for an android TV receiver. It's an app that manages TV channels. Now, since the team working on the receiver's updates seems not very picky about some details, I thought maybe I have to do the changes I need myself.

So **first**, some of the text involves some french characters, namely accents, which are not displayed the right way, they are replaced by random characters such as "Ȼ", "Ø" .... I thought that was an encoding problem, so I decompiled the apk using Apktool and checked some XML files but found UTF-8 in the header of all them.

**Second**, some text zones are somehow "shifted", they aren't in their right positions. I'm willing to adjust the positionning of these text zones.

So, do you think there is any possibility I can solve these two problems ? How can I identify which part in the apk file treats a specific zone in the app in order to reduce my "search zone" ?

Answer (score 0):

To put it simple: No you can't. There is not really a way to modify an apk.

You could recreate the app. You can take the decompiled code, read some android dev tutorials and write your own app with the old one as a base.

But there is also a problem with that. The decompiled code is probably obfuscated, to prevent such practicies, and to secure their code.

Again: But if you just want to reposition some text fields, it's probably possible. If you open an APK like a zip file (basically it's just that) you have the res folder. In it, there are the layout files. You just have to modify some of them and then you can repack the zip and rename it to an apk. I'm very confident that this method should work.